# Horizontally Flipping Text Halfway Around a Circle with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am making a Sunburst chart and am almost complete, but I want the text to flip half-way around the circle to make it easier to read.  Using help from another question here on stackoverflow I have been able to get the text to flip, but it drops down a level.  I have tried modifying the computeTextRotation function to account for this, but to no prevail. I am curious if anyone is able to help me solve this problem.

Here is a picture of the chart:

[image]

Here is the computeTextRotation functions code:

```
function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var rotation = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
    return {
        global: rotation,
        correction: rotation > 90 ? 180 : 0
    };
}
...
        .attr("transform", function(d) 
          {
            var r = computeTextRotation(d);
            return "rotate(" + r.global + ")"
              + "translate(" + radius / 3. * d.depth + ")"
              + "rotate(" + -r.correction + ")";
          }
        )
```

Here is the entire JavaScript code:

```
var margin = {top: 500, right: 500, bottom: 500, left: 500},
    radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 150;

function filter_min_arc_size_text(d, i) {return (d.dx*d.depth*radius/1)>14};

var hue = d3.scale.category10();

var luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, 1e6])
    .clamp(true)
    .range([90, 20]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); })
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx - .01 / (d.depth + .5); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return radius / 3 * (d.depth + 1) - 1; });

//Tooltip description
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("opacity", 0);

function format_number(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


function format_description(d) {
  var description = d.description;
      return  '<b>' + d.name + '</b></br>'+ d.description + '<br> (' + format_number(d.value) + ')';
}

function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var angle=(d.x +d.dx/2)*180/Math.PI - 90

    return angle;
}

function mouseOverArc(d) {
             d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")

          tooltip.html(format_description(d));
          return tooltip.transition()
            .duration(50)
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
        }

function mouseOutArc(){
    d3.select(this).attr("stroke","")
    return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
}

function mouseMoveArc (d) {
          return tooltip
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
}

var root_ = null;
d3.json("data/davis-aroma-wheel.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  // Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
  // Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
  // and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.

  partition
      .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .nodes(root)
      .forEach(function(d) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.sum = d.value;
        d.key = key(d);
        d.fill = fill(d);
      });

  // Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
  partition
      .children(function(d, depth) { return depth < 3 ? d._children : null; })
      .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });

  var center = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius / 3)
      .on("click", zoomOut);

  center.append("title")
      .text("zoom out");

  var partitioned_data = partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partitioned_data)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
      .each(function(d) { this._current = updateArc(d); })
      .on("click", zoomIn)
          .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
      .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
      .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);


  var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(partitioned_data)
      .enter().append("text")
          .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
          .attr("dx", "6") // margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
        .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})

  function zoomIn(p) {
    if (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
    if (!p.children) return;
    zoom(p, p);
  }

  function zoomOut(p) {
    if (!p.parent) return;
    zoom(p.parent, p);
  }

  // Zoom to the specified new root.
  function zoom(root, p) {
    if (document.documentElement.__transition__) return;

    // Rescale outside angles to match the new layout.
    var enterArc,
        exitArc,
        outsideAngle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

    function insideArc(d) {
      return p.key > d.key
          ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 0, dx: 0} : p.key < d.key
          ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 2 * Math.PI, dx: 0}
          : {depth: 0, x: 0, dx: 2 * Math.PI};
    }

    function outsideArc(d) {
      return {depth: d.depth + 1, x: outsideAngle(d.x), dx: outsideAngle(d.x + d.dx) - outsideAngle(d.x)};
    }

    center.datum(root);

    // When zooming in, arcs enter from the outside and exit to the inside.
    // Entering outside arcs start from the old layout.
    if (root === p) enterArc = outsideArc, exitArc = insideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

     var new_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

    path = path.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; });

     // When zooming out, arcs enter from the inside and exit to the outside.
    // Exiting outside arcs transition to the new layout.
    if (root !== p) enterArc = insideArc, exitArc = outsideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

    d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function() {
      path.exit().transition()
          .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
          .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d)); })
          .remove();

      path.enter().append("path")
          .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
          .on("click", zoomIn)
             .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
         .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
         .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
          .each(function(d) { this._current = enterArc(d); });


      path.transition()
          .style("fill-opacity", 1)
          .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });



    });


     texts = texts.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; })

     texts.exit()
             .remove()
    texts.enter()
            .append("text")

    texts.style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })
          .attr("dx", "6") // margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
      .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
          .transition().delay(750).style("opacity", 1)


  }
});

function key(d) {
  var k = [], p = d;
  while (p.depth) k.push(p.name), p = p.parent;
  return k.reverse().join(".");
}

function fill(d) {
  var p = d;
  while (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
  var c = d3.lab(hue(p.name));
  c.l = luminance(d.sum);
  return c;
}

function arcTween(b) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, b);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function updateArc(d) {
  return {depth: d.depth, x: d.x, dx: d.dx};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your corrective factor rotates the text 180 degrees, this is only half of what you need:

By rotating 180 degrees, you get text that is right way up, but now that moves in the opposite direction because the direction of the text is also rotated.

For the second half of the circle, you need to specify a text-anchor of "end" so that the text is anchored where it should be. Currently it is anchored where it starts, which is fine for the first half of the circle.

When styling the text you'll need to perform a check to see if the text anchor needs to be set to "end" as opposed to "start":

```
text.style("text-anchor",function(d) { return isRotated(d) ? "end" : "start" })
```

With the check looking something like:

```
function isRotated(d) {
    var rotation = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
    return rotation > 90 ? true : false
}
```

The margins also need to be adjusted:

```
.attr("dx", function(d) {return isRotated(d) ? "-6" : "6"}) //margin
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you so much for your answer!
There were two minor errors in the code which I edited in your post.
I also needed to adjust the margins, and I added that code to your post.

Comment: Glad it worked - sorry for the errors, I should have caught the margin thing, and the `,` instead of `:` was just absent mindedness on my part